# how to use home_dir() as a variable?

Tags: rust

My goal is to get the user's home directory, append my fixed string 'my_dir' to it, and print out all files in that directory.

I have a bunch of fragments that do some stepping stones of it, but I am new to Rust and having trouble piecing it together.

This:

```
match home::home_dir() {
    Some(path) =>  println!("homedir {}", path.display()),
    None => println!("Impossible to get your home dir!"),
}
```

prints out the home dir correctly, but I can't figure out how to store this in a variable.

If I had the home dir in a &str, I can concatenate like below:

```
    let home_dir: &str = "c:\\this\\is\\my\\home\\";//NEED HOME DIR HERE
    let my_dir: &str = "my_dir";
    
    let file_dir = format!("{}{}", home_dir, my_dir);
println!("{}", file_dir);
```

Once I have that, I can print each file with:

```
    for e in WalkDir::new(file_dir).into_iter().filter_map(|e| e.ok()) {

        let mut path_str = e.path().display().to_string();

        if e.metadata().unwrap().is_file() {
            println!("file is {}", e.path().display());
```

Comment: It seems `home::home_dir()` returns an `Option`, does this answer your question: [How can I pull data out of an Option for independent use?](/q/64996954/2189130) You probably want `home::home_dir().expect("Impossible to get your home dir!")` in this case.

Comment: `clone()` or perhaps `Cow`?

Comment: Thanks. home::home_dir().expect("Impossible to get your home dir!") sent me on the right path.

Comment: Since `home_dir` returns a [`Path`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html), it's better to append to it with [`home_dir.join ("mydir")`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.join) rather than converting to string and using `format`

Comment: @Jmb Since it is a `PathBuf`, it is even better to use [`push()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.push).